# Can .d.ts declarations add `as const` assertions to exports?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TS, I can write a constant with a [`const assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) as long as it's done *immediately* after a literal.

```
export const stuff = {
  a: {
    b: "xyz"
  }
} as const
```

This makes `typeof stuff` very strict, allowing TS to leverage the *values* of the type. It knows that `stuff.a.b` is and will always be `"xyz"`, which can be useful in performing conditional typing, lookups, etc.

If I have the same structure in a `.js` file, it obviously can't have the `as const` assertion:

```
export const stuff = {
  a: {
    b: "xyz"
  }
}
```

**Is there any way I can add the `as const` assertion to the export in the declaration file?**

Comment: In a `.d.ts` file you'd only declare the type anyway? Just type the property as `"xyz"` instead of `string` and you're done.

Comment: @Bergi So, no "DRY" way to accomplish this? Your advice is just, "duplicate the whole structure"?

Comment: A separate declaration file will by definition need to duplicate the structure, won't it?

Comment: I mean, *sort of*. A separate definition could provide generalized types for an export, right? Or, it could describe a structure that's generated at runtime. Or, the definition could be short-handed with type mapping. Etc. ... It seemed more likely to me that my google-fu was bad than that adding a constant assertion was impossible ... but, it sounds like I'm out of luck?